# python remove dtype and the end of an array and get list of lists

Tags: python

Does any one know how to convert this array into a python list, my ultimate result should be [[1,2,3],[4,6,8]] . Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import*


a = [array([  1,   2,   3], dtype=int16), array([4, 6, 8], 
    dtype=int16)]
```

Comment: Why do you even have a list of arrays, and why do you want a list of lists instead of a 2D array?

Comment: Aside: you really don't want to do `from numpy import *`.  It can cause subtle problems you don't want to spend time being puzzled over.  Use the `np.` approach instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
x = [list(i) for i in a]
```

output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, 8]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use Numpys [tolist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) function.

> np.array(a).tolist()